# Selecting a file in Explorer for use in Java

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to write a program that will make a copy of a preexisting file in the same directory with a different name for the new file.  I have already programmed all the 'behind the scenes' actions of the file copy.  What I want to do now is make it so that when the program is launched, a windows explorer dialog window pops up and asks to select the original file to be copied.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Search for Swing and JFileChooser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java Swing, use a "[File chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)."

If you need it, I can type up an example.

Comment: Sorry if this may seem like a silly question, but is swing included in java, or does it require the downloading of external classes?  Other than that, I don't believe that I need you to type an example, though I do appreciate the offer.

Comment: @user3317176-By downloading the JDK,it comes wrapped in it!

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, is the general term for the action I wish to perform 'File Choosers'?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating the JavaFX application. It's included in modern Java distributions. Just look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm). For example, that would be something like

```
package blahblah;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BlahBlah extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        // add some elements to root

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        //for example:
        System.out.println("File chosen: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is certainly a very nice looking option, but it appears that the knowledge to use this code may be a bit beyond me.  I'll read the documents and see if that helps though.  Also, is this included within the JDK, or does it require the downloading of external classes?

Comment: It's included in JDK since 7 (I don't remember update)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)  class. It's a class included in JDK. No need to have any third part library.

You can find a simple example [here](http://www.java-forums.org/java-tip/6584-jfilechooser-example-selecting-directory.html)

Comment: Did you add anything specific to it???
Please post answers only if the answer isn't present previously,don't just add answers for the sake of getting upvotes,it may fetch you downvotes rather!